# Latest Ionic (6) Capacitor not working on Android 6

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am building an app with Ionic Angular and Capacitor.
According to Capacitor's documentation, they support Android from version 5.0:

> Android version support for Capacitor is more complex than iOS. Currently, we are targeting API level 21 or greater, meaning Android 5.0 (Lollipop) or above. This represents over 90% of the Android market.

But when I try to launch my App in Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow on a real device, not the emulator which I know uses very old WebViews, I get this error from Logcat:

> 2023-02-07 20:17:30.316 1291-1291/com.my.app E/ApkAssets: Error while
> loading asset assets/natives_blob_64.bin:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/natives_blob_64.bin
>
> 2023-02-07 20:17:30.316 1291-1291/com.my.app E/ApkAssets: Error while
> loading asset assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin
>
> 2023-02-07 20:17:33.179 1291-1291/com.my.app E/Capacitor: System
> WebView is not supported
>
> 2023-02-07 20:17:33.300 1291-1381/com.my.app E/libEGL:
> validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
>
> 2023-02-07 20:17:33.546 1291-1291/com.my.app E/Capacitor/Console:
> File: http://localhost/ - Line 80 - Msg: Uncaught SyntaxError:
> Unexpected token (

I already tried with several browserslistrc configs and setting the target in tsconfig.ts to es2015, but nothing works.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "author": "John Smith",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "android": "ionic capacitor sync && ionic capacitor open android",
    "ios": "ionic capacitor sync && ionic capacitor open ios",
    "androidProd": "ionic capacitor sync && ionic capacitor build android --prod",
    "iosProd": "ionic capacitor sync && ionic capacitor build ios --prod",
    "buildProd": "ionic capacitor sync && ionic build --prod"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults and supports es6-module",
    "maintained node versions"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.2",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/device": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/diagnostic": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/local-notifications": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/power-optimization": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/screen-orientation": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/social-sharing": "^6.3.0",
    "@capacitor-community/facebook-login": "^4.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^4.6.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "^4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.6.1",
    "@capacitor/ios": "4.6.1",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^4.1.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^4.1.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.3.9",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-power-optimization": "^0.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.4",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^2.0.4",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^7.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "luxon": "^3.1.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.6.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "swiper": "^8.4.5",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~15.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.0.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^4.6.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.45.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.45.1",
    "eslint": "^8.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "39.6.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  },
  "description": "An absolute awesome app"
}
```

This is my tsconfig.ts:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

I really need to get this running on Android 6 as this app needs to go through a review process from Meta to use some Facebook/Instagram data, and they are testing on Android 6 Marshmallow devices, but as long as this error appears, the app will show the splash screen and then just display a white screen.

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with your version of capacitor and everything to do with the version of Chrome available on the Android device. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-a-specific-version-of-webview/219813

Comment: And how can I make my app run on those Chrome versions?

Comment: You don't. Also Android 5 is no longer supported. I guess you could downgrade everything but that seems like a bad idea. `"API 22+ (Android 5.1 or later) is supported, which represents over 95% of the Android market. Capacitor requires an Android WebView with Chrome version 60 or later. On Android 5 and 6, Capacitor uses the Android System WebView. On Android 7+, Google Chrome is used.`

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android

Comment: Okay, that's sad to hear, but thank you for the explanation.

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I have the same issue on my application

Comment: @RaGu, what's your issue? this question is very old, you should have created your own with up to date information instead of offering a bounty here.
If you want to support Android 21 it's not possible.

Comment: @JulioCesar I'm encountering a similar issue. My application requires undergoing a review process by Meta to access certain Facebook/Instagram data. I'm encountering the error System WebView is not supported. I attempted to update the WebView version in my Android 6 emulator, but I couldn't locate an option to update the WebView since it's utilizing a Google API. Consequently, the emulator doesn't have the Google Play Store app installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in the emulator for different older Android versions. The solution was to **update Chrome and System Webview** via Google Play in order to make the app launch properly again. Project-wise I didn't need to make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the `WebView` from the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview) or change the `capacitor.config.ts`:

```
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  ...
  android: {
    minWebViewVersion: 55
  },
};
```

From the [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config#schema):

> The minimum supported cannot be lower than version `55`, which is required for Capacitor.
>
> If the device uses a lower WebView version, an error message will be shown on Logcat.
>
> If `server.errorPath` is configured, the WebView will redirect to that file, so can be used to show a custom error.